# JavaScript Arrays with while loop

Tags: javascript, arrays

In this code it is supposed to find the age of the "var dob" then loop through the array to find the grade the student would be in.

I have been told that I have the proper code to find the person's age.
I also have the proper array. My problem seems to be in my while loop.

I have an error in my syntax in my while loop.

```
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

        var dob = '20120810';
        var year = Number(dob.substr(0, 4));
        var month = Number(dob.substr(4, 2)) - 1;
        var day = Number(dob.substr(6, 2));
        var today = new Date();
        var age = today.getFullYear() - year;
        if (today.getMonth() < month || (today.getMonth() == month && today.getDate() < day)) {
      age--;
    }
    //document.write("You are " + (age + 1) + " Years old"+"<br>");

    var grade = [
        [6,'Grade 1'],
        [7,'Grade 2'],
        [8,'Grade 3'],
        [9,'Grade 4'],
        [10,'Grade 5'],
        [11,'Grade 6'],
        ];

    while (var age = 0; age < grade; age++){
          document.write(grade[age]);
    }


    </script>
```

Comment: Change from `while` to `for`, that looks like that.

Comment: You have lists within lists here. If you intend to access 6,7,8,9 etc.. then you would need to do something like `grade[i][0]` - lists are zero based... And use `i` in your loop. https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp Try this  `alert(grade[0][0]);` then `alert(grade[1][0]);`

Comment: You also can't compare an integer to an array/list (`age < grade`) `grade.length` may have been what you were after instead of grade on its own.

Comment: You also have age in the loop and and in the calculation. If grade[i] == age would be what you probably need to then lookup grade[i][1] - to give Grade 1 etc

Comment: I suggest taking a look at the [*while*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/while)-loop and [*for*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for)-loop documentation. You'll notice that a *while*-loop can't have the syntax you've used in you question.

Answer (score 2):

Some of your errors are
1. You are comparing (int)age with an (array)grade
The best way would be `age < grade.length`
2. The index of `grade` array is from 0 to 5, that is `grade[0] == [6, 'Grade 1']`, which means if the age is greater than 5, you won’t have a result.

An alternative way, if you really want to print out the grade that corresponds to the age is,

```
    // age = 7;
    let yourGrade = grade.find(e => {
        return e[0] == age;
    });
    // console.log(yourGrade); // [7, 'Grade 2']
    // console.log(yourGrade ? yourGrade[1] : "You’re either too young or too old");
    // Grade 2
```

The code above tries to look through your (array)grade and returns the first occurrence of the value whose first item equals the calculated age.

There are many ways to achieve this.
*EDIT*
Alternatively, if you’re particular about the `while` loop, you can do the following:

```
    //age = 7;
    let yourGrade;
    let i = grade.length;
    while(i––) {
        if (grade[i][0] == age) {
            yourGrade = grade[i];
            break;
        }
    }
    console.log(yourGrade);
    //[7,'Grade 2']
    //try with age = 5 //undefined
```

Comment: Only thing I'd change is this... `console.log((yourGrade == null) ? "No grade for age" : yourGrade[1]);`

Comment: That’s true. To actually check if there’s a suitable grade for the calculated age and to log the grade itself, and not the array that contains the grade. I’ll update the answer.

Comment: You *while*-loop contains invalid syntax. The *while*-clause should not contain `;` and should contain a single expression.

Comment: @JGFMK `(yourGrade == null)` seems like an ant-pattern. Why not use `console.log(yourGrade ? yourGrade[1] : "No grade for age");`?

Comment: @JGFMK I agree with that. It should be stated the other way round.

Comment: @3limin4t0r I disagree. You don't have to think with way I wrote it. Takes more processing time for the old brain the way you wrote it. Code says what it does on tin as written.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably the best solution for you if you are looking for age and grade.

Remember the grade here is two dimentional array and you are comparing the first index element of grade with age. So you need to first find the max from first elements of grade array.

```
var dob = '20120810';
var year = Number(dob.substr(0, 4));
var month = Number(dob.substr(4, 2)) - 1;
var day = Number(dob.substr(6, 2));
var today = new Date();
var age = today.getFullYear() - year;
if (today.getMonth() < month || (today.getMonth() == month && today.getDate() < day)) {
    age--;
}
console.log("You are " + (age + 1) + " Years old");

var grade = [
[6,'Grade 1'],
[7,'Grade 2'],
[8,'Grade 3'],
[9,'Grade 4'],
[10,'Grade 5'],
[11,'Grade 6'],
];

maxAge=grade.reduce(function(max, grade) { 
    return Math.max(max, grade[0]); 
}, -Infinity);

for (i = 0; i < maxAge; i++){
    if(typeof grade[i] !== 'undefined' && grade[i][0]==age){
        console.log(grade[i][1]);
    }
}
```

Another alternative could be :

```
var dob = '20120810';
var year = Number(dob.substr(0, 4));
var month = Number(dob.substr(4, 2)) - 1;
var day = Number(dob.substr(6, 2));
var today = new Date();
var age = today.getFullYear() - year;
if (today.getMonth() < month || (today.getMonth() == month && today.getDate() < day)) {
    age--;
}
//console.log("You are " + (age + 1) + " Years old");

var grade = [
[6,'Grade 1'],
[7,'Grade 2'],
[8,'Grade 3'],
[9,'Grade 4'],
[10,'Grade 5'],
[11,'Grade 6'],
];

let yourGrade = grade.find(e => {
    return e[0] == age;
});
console.log('Age: ' + yourGrade[0] + ' and Grade: ' + yourGrade[1]);
```

Comment: In your first code example, you set maxGrade to the maximum instance of `grade[0]` which is actually the age but not the grade. You might want to correct that.

Comment: that is absolutely correct, grade[0] is the max age, thats how the for loop is going to end, during this loop I am just searching mached age which is previously determined and retuning the grade (grade[i][0]) if matched.

Comment: `grade[0]` is the max age but you attached it to a variable named `maxGrade`, ain’t that confusing for the readers?